# Why mininet python api works only once?

Tags: python, mininet

I have the following script,

```
 mininet>py h2.sendCmd('python listen.py 10.0.0.2') & h3.sendCmd('python listen.py 10.0.0.3')
```

It works the first time, but I get a message in mininet shell as below,

```
 unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

And if I run the same script subsequently, it doesn't work anymore. Does anyone know why this behaviour occurs and how to get rid of it.

listen.py is a python script to listen on a socket and create a file to save the received data, it works perfectly when I run it on individual xTerm of hosts.

Comment: Are you trying to `binary and` (&) the results of the two `sendCmd` calls?

Comment: No, I am trying to execute them in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mininet>py h2.sendCmd('python listen.py 10.0.0.2') & h3.sendCmd('python listen.py 10.0.0.3')
```

will cause the result (return values) of the two calls to be operated via bitwise `and` op

Try this

```
mininet> xterm h2 h3
```

And in the xterms, issue the commands